# gqlgen go, reduce db calls by adding one resolver

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I'm having some trouble resolving a specific situation which results in performances reduction.
I'm quite sure that is something which can be done, but I can't figure oute how to do it.

Here's an example schema for exposing the problem:

```
type Answer{
    answerId: String!
    text: String!
    topic: Topic!
}

type Topic {
    topicId: String!
    name: String!
    level: Int!
}
```

```
extend type Query {
    answer(answerId: String!): Answer!
    answers: [Answer!]! 
}
```

I've followed the documentation, expecially this part https://gqlgen.com/getting-started/#dont-eagerly-fetch-the-user
From my schema, It generates the following resolvers:

```
func (r *queryResolver) Answer(ctx context.Context, answerId string) (*models.Answer, error) {
...
#Single Query which retrives single record of Answer from DB.
#Fills a model Answer with the Id and the text
#Proceeds by calling the Topic resolver
...
}

func (r *queryResolver) Answers(ctx context.Context) ([]*models.Answer, error) {
...
#Single Query which retrives list of Answers from DB
#Fills a list of model Answer with the Id and the text
-->#For each element of that list, it calls the Topic resolver
...
}


func (r *answerResolver) Topic(ctx context.Context, obj *models.Answer) (*models.Topic, error) {
...
#Single Query which retrives single record of Topic from DB
#Return a model Topic with id, name and level
...
}
```

When the `answer` query gets called with `answerId` parameter, the `answer` resolvers gets triggered, it resolves the `text` property and calls the `Topic` resolver.
The `Topic` resolver works as expected, retrives a `Topic` it merges it inside the `Answer` and return.

When the `answers` query gets called without `answerId` parameter, the `answer` resolvers gets triggered, it retrives a list of `answers` with a single query.
Then, for each element of that list , it calls the `Topic` resolver.
The `Topic`  retrives a `Topic` and it merges it inside the single  `Answer` and return.

The results it's ok in both cases, but the `answers` query as a performance problem if I'm asking for a lot of Answers.
For each of the answer, the `Topic` resolver gets triggered and performs a query to retrive a single record.

Ex. If I've 2 Answers --> 1 Query for `[Answer0, Answer1]`, then 1 Query for  `Topic0` and 1 for `Topic1`

Ex. 10 Answers --> 1 for `[Answer0, ..., Answer9]` and then 10 for each `TopicN`

I would like to obtain some `topic` array resolver like

```
func (r *answersResolver) Topics(ctx context.Context, obj *[]models.Answer) (*[]models.Topic, error) {
...
#Single Query which retrives list of Topics from DB
#Return a list of model Topic with id, name and level
...
}
```

And I expect every element of the returned array to merge with the corresponding element of the `Answers` array.

Is it possible in some way? Where I can find an example of such approach?
Thanks

Comment: look into [dataloaders](https://gqlgen.com/reference/dataloaders/). gqlgen integrates with [`vektah/dataloaden`](https://github.com/vektah/dataloaden). There is also an [example](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/tree/master/_examples/dataloader) in the module repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be solved using Dataloaders ([docs](https://gqlgen.com/reference/dataloaders/))

I had to implement the following datasource for `Topics`:

```
package dataloader

import (
    "github.com/graph-gophers/dataloader"
)

type ctxKey string

const (
    loadersKey = ctxKey("dataloaders")
)


type TopicReader struct {
    conn *sql.DB
}

func (t *TopicReader) GetTopics(ctx context.Context, keys dataloader.Keys) []*dataloader.Result {
    topicIDs := make([]string, len(keys))
    for ix, key := range keys {
        topicIDs[ix] = key.String()
    }
    res := u.db.Exec(
        r.Conn,
        "SELECT id, name, level
        FROM topics
        WHERE id IN (?" + strings.Repeat(",?", len(topicIDs-1)) + ")",
        topicIDs...,
    )
    defer res.Close()

    output := make([]*dataloader.Result, len(keys))
    for index, _ := range keys {
            output[index] = &dataloader.Result{Data: res[index], Error: nil}
    }
    return output
}

type Loaders struct {
    TopicLoader *dataloader.Loader
}


func NewLoaders(conn *sql.DB) *Loaders {
    topicReader := &TopicReader{conn: conn}
    loaders := &Loaders{
        TopicLoader: dataloader.NewBatchedLoader(t.GetTopics),
    }
    return loaders
}

func Middleware(loaders *Loaders, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        nextCtx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), loadersKey, loaders)
        r = r.WithContext(nextCtx)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func For(ctx context.Context) *Loaders {
    return ctx.Value(loadersKey).(*Loaders)
}

func GetTopic(ctx context.Context, topicID string) (*model.Topic, error) {
    loaders := For(ctx)
    thunk := loaders.TopicLoader.Load(ctx, dataloader.StringKey(topicID))
    result, err := thunk()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result.(*model.Topic), nil
}
```

Comment: I have a question about gqlgen can you [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185153/99designs-gqlgen-get-child-parameters-from-rctx)